# Difference between dates in hour in bash

Tags: bash, scripts

How can I find the difference between two dates which are in the format

```
date +"%H-%M-%d-%m-%Y"
```

And also I want the difference in hours. How can I find this using a single command.

Comment: It's easier if you print in a more standard format, like `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM`. Anyway, you'll need to use multiple commands. Or a Python/Perl/Awk/etc. mini-script

Comment: @muru I am searching for the best solution you can provide

Comment: Aren't we all searching for the best solution?

Comment: Do I need to find it manually ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the dates are in a file a one-per-line, like, say:

```
16-49-24-02-2016
16-49-25-02-2016
```

Then you could use `awk`:

```
awk -F- 'NR==1 {
  then = mktime(sprintf("%s %s %s %s %s 00", $5, $4, $3, $1, $2))
}
NR==2 {
  now = mktime(sprintf("%s %s %s %s %s 00", $5, $4, $3, $1, $2)); 
  printf "%s\n", (now - then)/3600
}' input.txt
```

The `mktime` function expects time in `YYYY MM DD HH MM SS`, so we split the given timestamp and convert it to that format (using `00` for seconds). The difference between the timestamps is in seconds, so we divide by 3600 to get the hours.